# Dumping numpy array into an excel file

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy

I am trying to dump numpy array into an excel file using savetxt method, but I am getting this weird error on the console:

```
.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And this is the details of the numpy array which i want to dump:

```
[[[ 0.47185326  0.07954808  0.02773202 ...,  0.05631305  0.08299649
    0.03780528]
  [ 0.62651747  0.06029205  0.01570348 ...,  0.03766847  0.06287122
    0.02287979]
  [ 0.72675145  0.04626036  0.0107195  ...,  0.02535284  0.04664176
    0.01519825]
  ..., 
  [ 0.10476404  0.57678992  0.04675674 ...,  0.02255989  0.06741234
    0.0170289 ]
  [ 0.13148287  0.47490281  0.06038339 ...,  0.03263607  0.07844847
    0.02505469]
  [ 0.14134221  0.35699606  0.07600202 ...,  0.04766588  0.09139989
    0.0386818 ]]]

Type of first_layer_output : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Shape of first_layer_output : (1, 921600, 10)
```

And I am using savetxt this way:

```
np.savetxt('test.csv', first_layer_output, delimiter=',')
```

I am not sure what's wrong here, thus any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you could use pandas, its really easy friendly to use.

```
import pandas as pd

## convert your array into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame (array)

## save to xlsx file

filepath = 'my_excel_file.xlsx'

df.to_excel(filepath, index=False)
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Small note, this has a dependency on 'openpyxl'

Comment: @zwep is `openpyxl` just for `xlsx` files or for all excel format files ?

Comment: @Tiendung from their documentation, I can see the following "openpyxl is a Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm/xltx/xltm files."

Comment: And how to write data out onto an existing Excel sheet? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Bit late, but might help others facing such an issue.

This error is because you appear to have set

> dtype = np.ndarray

when creating / defining your Numpy matrix first_layer_output.

One solution to this problem is modifying your command storing the

```
np.savetxt('test.csv', first_layer_output, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
```

This command now outputs the contents of the array as a string, irrespective the actual data types being used.
Hope this helps.