# write 1D numpy array to excel using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, numpy

For example, I have the following code where I am trying to write array a to excel file

```
a = array([1, 2, 3])
write_excel(a)
```

The function that I wrote is as follow:

```
def write_excel(numpy_array):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\Users\\GTS\\Desktop\\Network \\rel.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for row, data in enumerate(numpy_array):
        worksheet.write_row(row, data)

    workbook.close()
```

I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/GTS/PycharmProjects/Rel1/Rel1.py", line 18, in <module>
    write_excel(a)
  File "C:\Users\GTS\PycharmProjects\Rel1", line 346, in write_excel
    worksheet.write_row(row, data)
  File "C:\Users\GTS\PycharmProjects\Rel1\venv\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 69, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: write_row() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

Comment: You could take some help from pandas, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875701/4985099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `write_row()` directly with a numpy array. Like this:

```py
def write_excel(numpy_array):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet.write_row(0, 0, numpy_array)

    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

write_row function takes arguments in the form of (row, col, data).
So use `worksheet.write_row(row, 0, data)` instead.

Comment: thank you, but I still received the following error: line 69, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs) line 1132, in write_row
    for token in data:
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function instead it works very well

```
def write_excel_one(numpy_array):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\Users\\GTS\\Desktop\\Network Interdiction Problem\\Manuscript\\rel.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for row, data in enumerate(numpy_array):
        # worksheet.write_row(row, 0, data)
        worksheet.write_number(0, row, data)
    workbook.close()
```