# ANSYS API DataTable to Excel file

Tags: python, c#, excel, for-loop, multiprocessing

I have a data in an array (B=[1,2,3,4,5]) which i took from the DataTable i tried python for loop to imported in excel file using this code:

```
def Cells(a,b):
    return str(chr(b+96) + str(a))
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as Excel
ex = Excel.ApplicationClass()
ex.Visible = True
workbook = ex.Workbooks.Open(r"F:\Programming\Excel\Plot data.xlsx")
worksheet=workbook.worksheets("Sheet1")

Adding_Max_Principal_Stress=Model.Analyses[0].Solution.AddMaximumPrincipalStress()
Model.Analyses[0].Solution.EvaluateAllResults()

A=Adding_Max_Principal_Stress.PlotData
B=A.Values[1]
C=B.Count

for i in range (C):
    E=B[i]
    worksheet.range(Cells(1+i,1)).Value=E
```

In this code, B contains the list of data like B=[1,2,3,4,5,...] the items in B has 100000 data(array values) which takes 5 hrs to import the data in excel. Is there any possibility that i can speed this process.

Comment: Do you have example data that we can use to test your script?

Comment: Sure Tom, I have a data B is an array contains 100000 data which is from 1 to 100000 like B=[1,2,3,4,5,6,..to..,100000], I'm trying to import that data in excel using for loop which takes longer time frame.

Comment: If in doubt, see if someone has done this before! In general, you dont want to use for loops especially when saving as an excel format. Here is an answer on how to save an array as an excel file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870968/dumping-numpy-array-into-an-excel-file

Is this faster?

Comment: Ya Tom, Thanks for sharing with me. The actual problem here is, I'm working in ANSYS API where i have a DataTable build using IronPython integrated with C#. Now, from the code we have `PlotData` which contains Table. I'm extracting the column values and importing in my excel `Plot data.xlsx` using for loop a you see in my code variable `B` contains the values like B=[1,2,3,4,5...upto 100000], is there any way that i can import the column parallely. between i couldn't import pandas –

Comment: Ive added some comments as an answer as there wasnt enough space on here!

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing IronPython doesnt support too many different Python libraries? In which case, the code needs to be almost pure python?

- Have you used a line profiler to see what the slowest part of the
  code is?
- It seems like in your .range formula you are only setting one cell at
  a time, have you tried setting all of the values at once? Each time that the VBA code has to interact with excel, it is very slow. If you can set all of the values of the cells at once, it will be much faster. I know how to do this in VBA code,
- Do you have to save as an excel file? Can you save as a CSV file instead? Creating large excel files is slow.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Tom, That's true Tom IronPython contains limited resources when it comes to excel part as per my findings,  1. I checked with profiler the whole program runs for    `600 secs = 10 mins` for 100000 data,  2. Ya Tom, That's right i'm setting one cell at a time (If it possible can you share the VBA code - for setting all of the values),  3. Ya Tom, I can use CSV also, I thought i can find someways in excel.

Comment: Hi Tom, could you share the code for CSV file.

Comment: @Manish Here is the documentation for saving data as a CSV: https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/csv.html

Comment: @Manish let me know if you need any help after looking at this.

Comment: Hi Tom Mclean, I have been using the documentation you shared started building the codes, Thanks Tom.

Comment: @Manish Great, have you had any success in reducing the saving time?

Comment: ya Tom, I got the code thanks a lot and also i have been trying to import column wise **now i am trying to import in different column to import like starting from B column in csv file**

Comment: @Manish Thats good, and did it run faster?

Comment: ya Tom, it took about 1 sec for two columns and per column has 1866 cells.