# Translating excel file writer matlab script to python

Tags: python, excel, matlab, matrix, translate

I am having trouble figuring out how to translate the following matlab script to python:

```
clc
clearvars
fileDir = cd;
outfile = 'OUT.xlsx'; % output file name 
fileNames = dir(fullfile(fileDir,'*.CSV'));
fileNames_sorted = natsortfiles({fileNames.name});
M= length (fileNames_sorted);
second_col= [];
for f = 1:M
%   option # 1 for numeric data only using importdata
    raw = importdata( fullfile(fileDir, fileNames_sorted{f}));
    second_col= [second_col raw(:,2)];  % extract the second column
end
% write all second columns lines into a matrix and store it in excel file 
writematrix(second_col,fullfile(cd,outfile));**
```

I'm not sure how to translate 'fullfile' and 'natsortfiles' to python functions?
This program copies the entire columns from the second row of every excel file in a folder and creates an output file that copies all of the entries into one matrix.
Thanks

Comment: For `fullfile` you can probably use `os.path.join()`. `natsortfiles` could probably be substituted with `sorted()` or `list.sort()`.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how I can translate the second_col= [second_col raw(:,2)] and the writematrix(second_col,fullfile(cd,outfile)) to python from matlab?

Comment: Are you using numpy? Are you familiar with MATLAB but not Python, or with Python but not MATLAB?

Comment: @nekomatic Yes, Im using numpy, Im familiar with using Matlab but not Python

Comment: OK so without doing all your work for you :-) I suggest you use `np.loadtxt` to read each input file, `np.hstack` to concatenate, and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875701/24447) for saving to .xlsx. For anything else see the numpy docs starting from https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html and if you get stuck, update the question with your Python code and explain what's going wrong.